# How to force an ip change on openshift?

Tags: openshift

I know that ip changes over time but is there a way to force openshift to change it every X hours without restarting (If not, I will consider restart) an application? Like some command, cartridge or cron script? Does this option become available with plan upgrade to bronze?

If there is absolutely no way to do that, can someone recommend me a platform similar to openshift which allows changing ip on fly.

Comment: What is your use case for wanting to change the ip address that often?

Answer (score 3):

With OpenShift Online, the applications are sometimes moved to a different node. However, users are unable to initiate or "force" moving to another node, thus changing the application's IP address (even with Bronze or Silver plans).

The other part of your question does not seem [suitable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) for Stack Overflow.